# Request Raw Data with Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

in my application, i have to send request parameter as raw data, But im not sure how to send it with VolleyRequest.

Request Parameter :

`{
    "category" : [
        {
            "itemcat_id": "a382e6f2-86d9-44e9-9e95-ad0007629000",
            "itemcat_outlet_id": "10",
            "itemcat_name": "Oreo Enak",
            "itemcat_status": "1",
            "itemcat_is_editable": "1",
            "itemcat_cdate" : "2018-04-17 15:35:20",
            "itemcat_ldate" : null
        }
    ]
}`

and How to send this data?

Comment: JsonObjectRequest also accepts a body object parameter if your endpoint expects JSON

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40100807/2308683

Comment: and if raw has jsonArray, how to parse it?

Comment: `new JSONArray(string)` parses things