# Upload some string to server and download with volley

Tags: android, android-volley

In my app, I need some string to be downloaded from server to use in the app. How can I upload the strings to the server?.

I've uploaded a text file at first but when sending request I received this error in logcat:

> Unexpected response code 307 for:

Also, I uploaded my text in a web page body same error happened.
Please help me how to upload some text or an `ArrayList` to the server and download with volley and use in the app.

This is my volley request method:

```
private void getOnlinePrice (){
   StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,URI_SHOW_PARAMS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
           String s=response;
           txtinfo.setText(s);
       }
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

       }
   });
   requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118803/6216498

Comment: you should use json encoded file system to easily handle data and pars it in your app

Comment: thank you for comment Please show me how to do that. I dont know what type of file i should upload and how download to use text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
                                 String HTTP_URL = "YOUR URL";




                                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(your_activity.this);


                    // sends data using POST method
                                    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HTTP_URL,
                                            new Response.Listener<String>()
                                            {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                                    String resp = response;

                                                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(resp))
                                                    {


                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "my response is" + resp,
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                                                    }
                                                    else{
                // if the response if empty
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "my response is empty",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            new Response.ErrorListener()
                                            {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                    // error

                                                }
                                            }
                                    ) {
                                        @Override
                                        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                                        {
                                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                            params.put("POST_VARIABLE_1", YourNamestring);
                                            params.put("POST_VARIABLE_2", YourNameString2);

                                            return params;
                                        }
                                    };
                                    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ill test it