# Sending Parameters in a POST request using Volley

Tags: android, post, android-volley

Trying to add Mangnet Link to a Premiumize Account using their API https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/premiumize.me/api/1.4#/transfer/transferCreate.

Response message:
`{"status":"error","message":"src is missing"}`

Code is as follows:-

```
void pushMagnet(final String apiKey, final String magnetLink, final Context context) {
    final String url = "https://premiumize.me/api/transfer/create?apikey=" + apiKey;

    Map<String, String> magnetSrc = new HashMap<>();
    //Parameters i want to send
    magnetSrc.put("src", magnetLink);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            //here added as an JSON Object
            new JSONObject(magnetSrc),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("Rest Response:", response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Rest Error:", error.toString());
        }
    }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

            return headers;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I've already tried this here as well: [Pass Parameter with Volley POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100807/pass-parameter-with-volley-post)

Comment: By looking at the swagger you need to add three different parameters, are you adding all of these?

Comment: I need to pick one of the first two parameters, the third one is optional. e. g. this curl command works without problems `curl -X POST "https://www.premiumize.me/api/transfer/create" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "src=samplemagnetlink"`

Comment: Have you made sure the content type is correct?

Comment: As Pointed out by Tomin, the Content-Type was indeed wrong, however i still get the same response from the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround:**

Use this Library and this code:

https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

```
void pushMagnet(final String apiKey, final String magnetLink, final Context context) {
    final String url = "https://premiumize.me/api/transfer/create?apikey=" + apiKey;
    JSONObject srcMagnet = new JSONObject();
    try {
        srcMagnet.put("src", magnetLink);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(new GzipRequestInterceptor()).build();
    AndroidNetworking.initialize(context, client);

    AndroidNetworking.post(url)
            .addHeaders("accept", "application/json")
            .addHeaders("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .addQueryParameter("src", magnetLink)
            .build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e("Server response:", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            Log.e("Server error:", anError.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: AndroidNetworking.initialize(context, client); should be in oncreate of application.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error is at the header parameter **"Content-Type"**.

You used incorrect header information `"multipaltform/form-data"`

Try adding the `"Content-Type"` to `"multipart/form-data"` to the header data.

The submission of MULTIPARTDATA is different from submission normal form. You have to use MultiPartEntity instead of Map.

Try following this link for Multipart Data: [How to send a “multipart/form-data” POST in Android with Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, edited the code, however the error still occurs.

Comment: Yeah, it is exactly the same. I get this error even when I don't overwrite the header.

Comment: Use some Rest API Clients to connect with server and check whether the API Call is working or not.

Comment: this curl request works: `curl -X POST "https://www.premiumize.me/api/transfer/create" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "src=samplemagnetlink"`

Answer (score 0):

For sending parameters in volley you need to override the getParams()

```
@Override
protected Map<String,String> getParams()
{

    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    // the POST parameters:
    params.put("src", magnetLink);
    Log.d("Volley","Volley params "+params);
    return params;

}
```