# How to send parameters using Android Volley to Azure Functions?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, azure-functions

I am trying to use Android Volley to call my functions within Azure, the call and response itself work fine but i cannot seem to work out how to send parameters from volley to the function, how do i pick up the key parameter within the azure function

```
public RequestComicPublishers(Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();

    String key = "8B2695ADAA2DA5F72768C44C9F327";
    params.put("key", key);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams()
{
    return params;
}
```

Currently i attempted the following in C# but have had no success

```
string key = req.Query["key"];
if(key == "8B2695ADAA2DA5F72768C44C9F327")
{
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100807/pass-parameter-with-volley-post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters maybe this helps ?

Comment: unfortunately this only will send the data as form-data :(

Comment: i see, hopefully someone can help you out though, i'm not a big volley fan or user myself so i'll upvote for you :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending general data as form-data i sent data using headers, as this is supported within azure functions! :D